# What process is locking file

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-server-2008-r2

There are millions of questions how to know what process is locking some file programmatically. However my boss told me today that since Windows 2008 R2 there is some new possibility. As far as now I can:

a. use Handle.exe in a subprocess and capture output

b. use some nasty long code that examines all the processes and enumerates handles opened by them

That is ok, but does anyone know about those new possibilities (I believe new API calls in Windows 2008R2)?

Comment: Why don't you ask your boss what new functionality he's talking about?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Bosses are not helpful. Bosses are inspring.

Comment: @RomanR. lol, true. However, when my boss says _"I heard of a diddlydoo that can do foobar without bazzing the quux"_, my natural response is _"Where did you hear that and how will it help us?"_. I don't go Googling for him.

Comment: Yup. Very smart. Maybe my boss is in a different time zone? Or maybe he (being also a developer) heard something during conference? I belive you guys know every API function by heart, so obviously asking about possibility of a new API is like asking for a d****.

Comment: @smok1 We don't know everthing by heart, we just know how to find the answer quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Raymond Chen answered my question with Restart Manager :)